# Magento Community Edition Multi-merchant Support

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am planning for an e-commerce project which will provide a marketplace e-commerce platform for merchants in my region.

I came across Magento Community Edition, seems very impressive But i did not understand the merchants support feature.

Does Magento Community Edition gives me the ability to create a website that support multi-merchants (sellers)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento does not support the marketplace scenario. However, you may find an extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=market+place&pl=0

Comment: Thank you Nils.
Another small question do you have any idea on any framework or open source script that do the marketplace ?
Thank you again

Comment: This has been done successfully with Intershop, but that is not open source:
http://www.intershop.com/press-release/intershop-powers-australias-first-online-furniture-marketplace

What traffic do you expect? Peak page views and orders per hour?

Comment: I am expecting a 4000 views per day for web platforms. Orders is not a thing that I can predict now.
But I also plan to develop a mobile App so the number could expand even further.
Generally I don't think that server stress will be a very big problem considering the small Tunisian market.